Any geographical information in the Saga of Darren Shan series?
The Saga of Darren Shan features several recurring locations, notably:

Mr Crepsley's hometown (main setting of books 3 and 8)
Darren and Steve's hometown (main setting of book 1)
Vampire Mountain (main setting of books 4, 5, and 6)

Is there any information about where in the world any of these might be? The author, after whom the main character is named, is Irish but born in London; is the fictional Darren also Irish? I remember an encounter with a bear in book 4 on the way to Vampire Mountain; does the description of the bear, or any other hints about the surroundings of the mountain (perhaps at the start of book 6), give us any clue about what continent it's in at least? What about Mr Crepsley's hometown?
Textual evidence from the original duodecalogy of books themselves is preferred, if possible. Extratextual evidence such as author interviews or other stories in the same world could also be OK, but I'd rather see an answer figuring out the locations from descriptions/clues in the original stories.
